# How to write sql query for getting data

Tags: sql

I have table with child and parent hierarchy within same table.
I have column to identify the parent of the respective node.
Records like

```
Id  name  Parent
1    ABC   Null
2    PQR   1
3    DEF   Null
4    LMN   Null
5    OPQ   Null
6    JKL    2
7    TUY    4

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
   Id INT,
   Name varchar(3),
   Parent INT
)

INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (1,’ABC’,Null)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (2,’PQR’, 1)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (3,’DEF’, Null)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (4,’LMN’, Null)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (5,’OPQ’, Null)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (6,’JKL’, 2)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (7,’TUY’, 4)
```

How to write query to find out parent who have child and id of child?
More-over  one  query to find the the children who dont have parent ?

Comment: Look at the self join. Also, show your efforts. Do you think about that it can be children?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not enough clear to me. The parents without childs should appear in the query? Do you want a record with each parent-son, or one row with this type: parentid-son1;son2;son3;?

As an example you can use this code:

```
SELECT p.id as parentid, h.id as sonid FROM #temp p INNER JOIN #temp h ON p.id = h.parent
```

Answer (score 0):

query to find out parent who have child and id of child

```
SELECT parent, id AS "Child"
FROM #Temp
WHERE Parent is not null
```

query to find the the children who dont have parent

```
SELECT id AS "Child"
FROM #Temp
WHERE Parent is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Not massively clear what your asking and assuming it is only the single table above, I think this would get that you want by just not including `NULLS`.

```
SELECT Id, name, parent
FROM #Temp
WHERE parent IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `Sql Server`. I will do this using `recursive cte`

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT id,name,Parent,0 AS level
         FROM   #Temp
         WHERE  Parent IS NULL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT b.id,b.name,b.Parent,level + 1
         FROM   cte a
                JOIN #Temp b
                  ON a.Id = b.Parent)
SELECT b.Id,b.Name,b.Parent
FROM   cte a
       JOIN cte b
         ON a.Parent = b.Id
WHERE  a.level >1
```